# how to Write in Django SlugField with hebrew

Tags: django, hebrew, slug

i need help how to write Hebrew in SlugField in django models

now i can write only English 
something like: hello-world
but i what to  write  in SlugField = "שלום-עולם"
and the url be like:
www.somsite.com/blog/שלום-עולם

10X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of the slugfield is that it converts a given string to only url-safe characters. Hebrew is unicode, which means that it generally is unsafe to use in the url. If you want to override this, just use your article title instead of a slugfield.